# Loop through all columns in a dataframe and sum if value is present in a certain column

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, sum, apply

Below is a sample data data set:

```
y<-c("A1","B1", "C2", "A1", "B1","C1", "A1","B2", "C3", "A1", "B1", "C4", "A1", "B1","C4", "A1","B2", "C4", "A1","B1", "C4", "A1", "B1", "C4")
     test<- data.frame(matrix(y, nrow = 3, ncol = 8))
     colnames(test) <- c("Learn_1", "Car_1", "Car_2", "Fan_1", "Fan_2", "Fan_3","Kart_1", "God_1")
     test
```

Is there a way using an apply function to loop through every column but the last and sum up the number of times a value is present only if found in the last column of a dataframe (thus using my last column as a index to search)? I know I can do this using a for loop, but is kind of long, maybe a way do this using an apply function?

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output for this sample input? (Be as specific as possible)

Comment: My desired output is a list or table of summations of the values that exist in the last column that appear in the other columns throughout the dataframe. My end goal is to plot this summation in a rectangle. Where the rectangle is the total number of genes in last column and broken down into percent shades (different colors). The percent shades are the proportion of values that show up 1 time, 2 times, 3 times, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the number of times a value corresponding to the value of the last column is found, per row, then this works:

`apply(test,1,FUN= function(x) length(which(x[-8]==x[8])))`

You can easily adapt it to any number of columns and even add it as a new column.

EDIT:

If it is for the whole dataset, then you can use:

```
test<-as.matrix(test);
table(test[,-8])[match(test[,8],names(table(test[,-8])))]
```

after your own code.

Comment: Ouostiti is there a way to do this, but the data is mixed up and may correspond on a different row then what I am checking?